# Codeforce Round #617 "Div3-B"

Tags: python

It works well in my computer, but when I submit my code, it reminds me of 'runtime error in test 1', what is the problem?

```
f_in = open('input.txt')
f_out = open('output.txt','w')

i=int(f_in.readline())
for t in range(0,i):
    a=int(f_in.readline())
    sum=a
    while(a >= 10):
        t=a//10
        a=a-10*t+t
        sum=sum+t
    f_out.write(str(sum)+'\n')
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Comment: Then what is the requirement, what is it inside `input.txt` and `output.txt`?

Comment: Do make your requirements clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code gets the input from a file, but this problem send the data from the standard input (stdin). Just use the input function.

You can verify if the problem send you data from a file or from the standard input on the header of the problem.

A example of file input problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/234/problem/A